# dynamic programming algorithm during an interview

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

This question was asked to me in an interview and it embarrassingly exposed my shortcomings on dynamic programming. I will appreciate if someone can help me crack this one. Also, it would be very helpful to me (and others) if you can explain your thinking process along the way as you devise the solution as i seem to be able to understand when i see a solution which uses dynamic programming paradigm but struggle to come up with my own.

Without further ado, here is the question i was asked.

Given an integer `i` and set `X` of `k` points `x1`, `x2`, ... `xk` on real line, select `i` points from set `X` so as to minimize the sum of the distance from every point in `X` to a point in `i` using Dynamic programming.

Comment: You know, unless the job was specifically for an operations research job, this strikes me as a disqualifying interview question.  That is, one should gently but firmly shake the hand of the interviewer, thank them, and explain that using this kind of silly question in an interview proves they are not the sort of place one should wish to be employed.

Comment: Do we remove the points in I from X? Because if not, I'm not sure I see a point to the question.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams it wouldnt matter, because i you didnt, then the sum would be 0.  The point of the question is to choose a subset with a fixed size such that the sum of distances from each point in X to the set is minimal, and you approach it in a similar manner to knapsack

Comment: Here is a hint.  Try to solve this related, but slightly easier to see problem.  Given an integer i and a set X of k points on the real line, select I points from set X so that the right-distance from every point in X to a point in I is minimized.  The right distance(a, b) = b - a if b > a, otherwise it's infinity.

Comment: @FooBah, you can do much better than solving this like knapsack.  It's definitely polynomial time.

Comment: This sounds like the kind of question Google asks for a job which actually mostly involves moving web elements a few pixels left or right. Charlie's right.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I would solve this question differently.  However, since the OP said he was asked this in an interview, its likely that the interviewer specifically said to use DP (and yes, it sounds stupid, but I've been asked questions like that before)

Comment: @CharlieMartin Unfortunately, at any sufficiently large employer, there will be interviewers who ask poorly chosen questions. This doesn't necessarily reflect on the company as a whole.

Comment: One stupid thing about this question is that it doesn't require `i < k` which means you could have `i > k` which makes the task completely redundant.

Comment: I think there's a problem with the question -- Do you mean i points in X that are the closest to i on the number line? What is point IN i mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With most DP problems I try and find a kind of reduce-and-conquer relation. That is, a relation whereby I can cut away from the problem size with each step (like divide and conquer, but usually doesn't divide the problem, it just removes a small part). In this problem (like many others) we can make a very simple observation: Either the first point is in the set of `i` points, or it isn't.

Some notation: Let's say X = {x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>k</sub>}, and denote the reduced set X<sub>n</sub> = {x<sub>n</sub>, x<sub>n+1</sub>, ..., x<sub>k</sub>}.

So the observation is that either x<sub>1</sub> is one of the `i` points, or it isn't. Let's call our `i`-set finding function MSD(`i`,X<sub>k</sub>) (minimum sum of distances). We can express that cut-away observation as follows:

MSD(`i`,X<sub>k</sub>) = Either MSD(`i-1`,X<sub>k-1</sub>) U {x<sub>1</sub>} or MSD(`i`,X<sub>k-1</sub>)

We can formalise the "either or" part by realising a simple way of checking which of those two options it actually is: We run through the set X and calculate the sum of the distances, and check which is actually the smaller. We note at this point, that that check has a running time of `ki` since we will naively run through each of the `k` points and grab the minimum distance from points in the set of size `i`.

We make two simple observations regarding base cases:

MSD(`i`,X<sub>i</sub>) = X<sub>i</sub>
MSD(`0`,X<sub>n</sub>) = {}

The first is that when looking for `i` points in a set of size `i` we obviously just take the whole set.
The second is that when looking for no points in a set, we return the empty set. This inductively ensures that MSD returns sets of size `i` (it's true for the case where `i=0` and by induction is true according to our definition of MSD above).

That's it. That will find the appropriate set.
Runtime complexity is upper bounded by `O(ik * step)` where step is our `O(ik)` check from above. This is because MSD will be run on parameters that range from `0-i` and X<sub>1</sub> - X<sub>k</sub>, which is a total of `ik` possible arguments.

That leaves us with a runtime of O((ik)<sup>2</sup>).

The following part is based on my understanding of the OP's question. I'm not sure if the distance of every point in X from the i-sized subset is the sum of the distances of every point from *every other point* in the subset, or the sum of the distances of every point in X *from the subset itself*.
I.e. sigma of x in X of (sum of distances of x from every point in the subset) OR sigma of x in X of (distance of x from the subset which is the minimum distance from x to any point in the subset)

I assume the latter.

We can reduce the runtime by optimising the `O(ik)` check from above. We notice that the elements are actually sorted (albeit in reverse order in this current notation), since when we add them on we do so always from the right hand side. Assuming they're sorted to begin with, they will be once out of the MSD routine. If they weren't sorted to begin with we can sort them, which will only cost `O(klogk)` anyway.

Once sorted, checking the distance of each point from a point in the set will be `k * logi` since for each point we do a binary search. This yields a total running time of `O(ik * klogi + klogk)`
= O(k<sup>2</sup> * ilogi).

Finally, we can express that as O(k<sup>3</sup>logk). Not the fastest solution, but a solution.

I'm sure there are even more optimisations, but that's my 2c.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for responding. Can you please explain how you deduced MSD(i,Xk) = Either MSD(i-1,Xk-1) U {x1} or MSD(i,Xk-1)?

Regards,

Comment: @user976078, that is indeed the key observation. Well, the set you are looking for is well-defined. It might not be unique although at least one such set definitely exists (proof: there are a finite amount of subsets of X of size i, therefore a well-defined property guarantees at least one minimum). If so, I can ask myself a question: is `x1` (the first element in X) in one of these minimum sets? At the outset I have no way of knowing. But I know that it either is, or it isn't. Right?

Comment: So now, I don't have to solve the larger problem of finding a minimum i sized subset of X, but rather it's enough to solve a slightly smaller problem: I want to be able to find MSD(i-1,Xk-1) which is an i-1 sized subset of Xk-1 which is a smaller set than X. That's useful if I assume that x1 **is** in one of these minimum sets. Although like we said, maybe it isn't. So I also want to be able to solve MSD(i,Xk-1), which is an i sized subset of Xk-1, again a slightly smaller problem. This solution would be useful is x1 **isn't** in one of these minimum sets.

Comment: If I can solve these two smaller problems (sub-problems), **and** determine which is indeed the smaller of the two, then I must have found the answer. To recap, we said either x1 is in the set we're looking for, or it isn't. So if I can solve the sub-problems and check which is more optimal, I can answer the question of whether x1 is present or not. And that leads to the recursive relation.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help so far. I have last follow up question. In your definition of MSD, what exactly is Xk as you define it? How does it change with each iteration? Are you starting with all X points and gradually shortening the set by one on each iteration?

Secondly, how do you know that this algorithm will give the minimal sum of distances from each point in X to the set? We could have done pretty much the same thing if we were computing the maximal sum. Right?

Comment: @user976078, I defined Xk above. It's the last k points from the original set. So Xk-1 is a proper subset of the original set, i.e. is smaller than it, since we take out 1 member. As to your second question, you can prove that it gives the minimum by induction. The base cases outlined all give the proper answer, and then induction follows. Indeed, you could have done the **exact** same thing for maximum, the only difference would be the check-step where instead of calculating and taking the minimum, you took the maximum.